# MutiLabel classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, text-classification

I have some 1000 news articles related to science and technology. I need to train a classifier which will predict say 3(computer science, electronics, electrical) confidence scores for each article. 
Each score represents how much the article belongs to each field.
The confidence score will be a value between zero and one.

But the data set doesn't have a training label.

How do I proceed from here? What kind of data do I need?
How do I train such a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is therefore not a classification problem.
It's unsupervised as long as you don't have any label.

What you can do is to look at K-Means (unsupervised Machine Leaning algorithm) that allows you to cluster you data into predefined number of cluster (here 3):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans

But you won't have any measure to verify the "ground truth"

If you really want to go further, you can try to label these articles yourself (with let's say computer science, electronics and electrical) and try some supervised algorithms (with *scikit-learn*) / neural net (with *tensorflow*).

The idea is to vectorize your input data (you can take a look at TF-IDF) and then try any supervised model.

This is called NLP. You also have libraries that can help you doing this.

NLTK & Spacy are a good start :

https://www.nltk.org/

https://spacy.io/

Comment: nice overview of the techniques

Comment: Thanks @prosti :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not super clear what is your main idea, but articles typically do have tags or categories and you may use that for the classification labels.

Humans are pretty good at articles tagging.